# Remove Duplicate from Dropdown in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, list, selenium, set, dropdown

If I want to remove duplicate from dropdown by using `Selenium WebDriver` and `Java` I found some solutions.

They store the elements in List then they use Set for remove duplicate as blow. Why we are using List then we store the list in Set? I know if there are multiple elements we need List but, can we use only Set without using List?

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(“dropdown“));
Select select= new Select(element)     
List<WebElement> list = select.getOptions();
Set set = new HashSet ();
for (WebElement element : list) {    
    set.add(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have used the `getOptions()` and if you check internally, the return type of it is `List<WebElement>` So, if you use `Set<WebElement>` directly it would throw to compile time error as `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<WebElement> to Set<WebElement>`

The internal implementation of the `getOptions()`

```
public List<WebElement> getOptions() {
return element.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
}
```

you can check it [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#getOptions())

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, now I understood the reason.

Comment: I would appreciate you if you accept the answer, So it would help other's to resolve their issue and understand the concept

Comment: I voted you by clicking the vote button, but I do not know that I did correctly or not. :) It was my first question and I do not know well the app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See,

**List**

> An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this
> interface has precise control over where in the list each element is
> inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index
> (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.

and

**Set**

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
> contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
> most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
> the mathematical set abstraction.

Now coming to your question,

```
Why we are using List then we store the list in Set? - it's cause return type of 
.getOptions(); is basically **List<WebElement>**, you need to typecast like below :-
```

**Sample code :**

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("dropdown"));
 Select select= new Select(element)  ;   
 HashSet<WebElement> listOfOptions = (HashSet<WebElement>) select.getOptions();
 for (WebElement ele : listOfOptions) {
     System.out.println(ele);
 }
```